# Draw path above text in svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, svg, annotations

I've researched a lot the past two days and I'm overwhelmed so please be nice.
What I'm trying to do is create an annotation above fragments of some text.

Lets say we have this sentence: "This is an example" .

So if I wanted to draw a shape (path) above "This is" fragment like this [image]
how would I go with it? (Imagine that "$1.65 billion" is "This is")

1. How can I have the start and the end of the fragment I want.
2. Do you know a library that will make this task easier?
3. How can I detect if one shape overlaps another (e.g. annotate "This is" and "is an").

This is going to be dynamic so, I have to be able to do the above in a dynamic way.

I'm not looking for code, just for guidance. I don't have any code myself because I really don't know where to start. Any help-tip would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
I'm a complete noob to svg. In my research I've stumbled upon Raphael.js and svg.js .

Comment: How do you generate the text? (ie does it have to be HTML tags or svg:text)

Comment: The text will be retrieved from a server, so I can generate it either way. Which approach is better?

Comment: Do you have an approximation of the word count of the text? Do you need to do this overlay a lot or only for specific words in the text?

Comment: I general the sentences are not very big. In general I might have to draw about 5-6 paths in one sentence. But I will have multiple sentences (in seperate divs - svgs). Efficiency is good thing to keep in mind, but what I really need is simplicity.

Comment: Since I'm retrieving the text from the server I can count the words before I begin drawing.

Comment: Last question: when do you need to activate the annotation? On mouse on? By code?

Comment: The annotation will be there from the beginning. So I'm not waiting for an event.

Comment: To the one that voted for the question to be closed. One question.. Why? Not even a comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd probably cut this into 2 different tasks:

1) **Text generation and annotation marking**: this is actually the harder part since you might have overlaps in your marker.

2) **Drawing the annotation**: once you have the coordinates of your markers, it's actually rather easy to draw the annotation using css and an svg background.

Here's an example to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/wAq4U/1/. I avoided the hard problem of annotation collision so you'll need to find a way to mark overlapping words.

In the example, I used plain html to write the sentence and mark the annotations with a span. Then I used css and javascript to position the annotations on top of each marker.

```
<div class="annotation-segment">
   This <span class="marker" data-anno-id="0">is a</span>
   <span class="marker" data-anno-id="1">sample</span> text
</div>
```

**Edit**:

Here's an example of using a svg background stretched to 100% to mark your annotation. I used the first SVG example I found on google for illustration but any SVG should work fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/wAq4U/3/

As for overlapping markers, that's an interesting problem and I'd appreciate an update how you manage to solve this problem.

**Edit 2**: Here's a more concrete example of how to use a SVG background to cover the length of the marker: http://jsfiddle.net/wAq4U/4/

Comment: I upvoted, but my biggest problem is the grouping. That's why I need that shape from start to end of the marker.

Comment: /* make an svg background for the annotation here */ . This is the part that I need the big help. How will the svg shape be dynamic and strecth or shrink depending on the size of the mark (segment)?

Comment: Check out my update, I scaled the annotation size to the same width as the marker. Note: this obviously won't work with multi-line sentences.

Comment: No this won't work. Check the curly shape in my image. That's what I need. It doesn't matter if it's curly, but it has to start and end on with the marker and distinguish that.(Thanks for the effort though)

Comment: Actually this is really good. Thnx. I'm not going to get a better answer than yours and you did what I asked, gave me something to work with. Accepted your answer